# Unicode fallback font

Tags: fonts, window-manager, display-manager

When the system displays a text, whose responsibility is to select the appropriate font for the letters?

Let's say I have the following 3 fonts installed and I open a website with letters and special characters. When and how does the system decide which fonts to use?

```
Default system font: ISO basic Latin alphabet
FontA: special characters only
FontB: basic alphabet + special characters
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most apps nowadays rely on the [fontconfig](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/fontconfig/) library to render fonts. Its configuration files usually provided with the package are documented and self-descriptive. System-wide conf. files placed in the /etc/fonts/conf.d/ directory. Fallback font settings are usually in the 60-latin.conf and 65-non-latin.conf files.

Answer (score 1):

On `/etc/fonts/conf.d/` the fallback shall be indicated on the specific font conf file.

For example, for Noto Sans we have to:

```
cd /etc/fonts/conf.d/
sudo yourTextEditor 66-noto-sans.conf
```

And put this inside the text file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Noto Sans</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>Noto Sans</family>
    <default>
      <family>sans-serif</family>
    </default>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

If it currently doesn't follow this format it could be that the package of your distro is defective, and you shall point them to this answer.